# jQuery select all siblings & children except self

Tags: javascript, jquery

What I'm trying to do is replicate an accordian type jQuery widget

I have the following code:

```
$('a').on('click', function (e) {
  var active = $(this).parent().next();
  active.toggleClass('active');
  active.siblings().not(active).removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Although active.siblings().not(active).removeClass('active'); does not work
how I want it to do I basically want it to select all siblings UL tags and any children UL tags of the siblings but exclude the Active/Current selection.

I have setup this fiddle as an example http://jsfiddle.net/7u3pw1hz/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is, the other `ul` elements are not siblings, they are children of sibling `li` elements of current `li`

```js
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  var active = $(this).parent().next();
  active.toggleClass('active');
  active.parent().siblings().children('ul').removeClass('active');
  active.find('ul').removeClass('active');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
ul ul.active {
  max-height: 800px;
}
ul ul {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><span><a href="category.html">Shop</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
    <ul class="active">
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Sleeping Bags</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="category.html">Medium Sleeping Bags</a></li>
          <li><a href="category.html">Winter Sleeping Bags</a></li>
          <li><a href="category.html">Summer Sleeping Bags</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Swaddles</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Linen</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Clothing</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">My Room</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Tool Box</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Wellbeing</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Feed</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Bath</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Carriers</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <span><a href="category.html">Gifts</a> <i class="icon-expand_more"></i></span>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/fitted-wraps">Fitted Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/merino-wraps">Merino Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/muslin-wraps">Muslin Wraps</a></li>
          <li><a href="/shop/wraps/stretch-cotton">Stretch Cotton</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><span><a href="category.html">Brands</a></span></li>
</ul>
```